# The application freezes when closing WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms, mono, webbrowser-control

I am new to WinForms and I'm trying to use the `WebBrowser` control on GNU/Linux with Mono. It runs fine, but when I close the form I get strange warnings, and the application freezes when I try to create another form containing a `WebBrowser`.

In fact I can launch as many browsers as I wish, until I close one. Then if I create a new one the app freezes.

Here is a sample code:

```
 public class TestForm : Form
 {
   Button button = new Button();

   public TestForm()
   {
     button.Parent = this;
     button.Text = "Run browser";
     button.Click += button_Click;
   }

   [STAThread]
   public static void Main()
   {
     Application.Run(new TestForm());
   }

   public void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     new MyBrowser("www.google.com").Show();
   }
 }

 class MyBrowser : Form
 {
   WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();

   public MyBrowser(string url)
   {
     browser.Parent = this;
     browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
     browser.Navigate(url);
   }
 }
```

Here are the warnings I get:

```
 (essai.exe:9108): Gdk-WARNING **: GdkWindow 0x2800094 unexpectedly destroyed

 (essai.exe:9108): Gdk-WARNING **: GdkWindow 0x2800093 unexpectedly destroyed

 (essai.exe:9108): Gdk-WARNING **: GdkWindow 0x280007e unexpectedly destroyed

 (essai.exe:9108): Gdk-WARNING **: GdkWindow 0x280007d unexpectedly destroyed

 (essai.exe:9108): Gdk-WARNING **: GdkWindow 0x280001c unexpectedly destroyed

 (essai.exe:9108): Gdk-WARNING **: GdkWindow 0x280001b unexpectedly destroyed

 (essai.exe:9108): Gdk-WARNING **: GdkWindow 0x280001a unexpectedly destroyed

 (essai.exe:9108): Gdk-WARNING **: GdkWindow 0x2800016 unexpectedly destroyed
```

So my question is: what am I doing wrong? Is it possible that the problem comes from Mono?

---

**Update**: on Windows it works if I add `[STAThread]` before `Main`'s definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe WebBrowser control from mono have some known issues.
Try to find mwf-DESIGNER, in mono site.